# Bayesian in R, the posterior of OLS with non-informative prior

Tags: r, bayesian, least-squares, posterior, uninformative-prior

I know that beta and sigma2 in Bayesian OLS could be simulated by standard distribution, i.e., sigma2 by inverse gamma and beta by normal.

Instead of that, as a beginner, I try to practice MCMC methods directly on the OLS posterior with non-informative. That is, (X contains a column of 1 to account the intercept, is it right?)

Prior: g(beta,sigma2) ~ 1/sigma2

Likelihood: y|beta,sigma2,X ~ N(X*beta,sigma2*I)

So posterior: beta,sigma2|y,X ~ N(X*beta,sigma2*I)*(1/sigma2)

I want to make sure sigma2 is positive, so I do variable transformation by sigma2=exp(eta). If I'm not wrong, the posterior will be changed to

New posterior: beta,eta|y,X ~ N(X*beta,eta*I)

Thus, in R, I write the following function for posterior,

```
b_ols<-function(theta,data){
  beta=theta[1:4] #theta[1] is for intercept
  sigma=sqrt(exp(theta[5])) #theta[5] is for eta

  x=data[,1:4]
  y=data[,5]

  logf<-function(x,beta,y,sigma)
    dnorm(y,mean=sum(x*beta),sd=sigma,log=TRUE)
  val=0
  for(i in 1:length(y))
    val=logf(x[i,],beta,y[i],sigma)
  return(val)
}
```

I have three IVs, stored in the 2nd to 4th column of data, the DV in the 5th column of data. Data[,1] contains a vector of 1 to account for the intercept. Similarly, theta includes beta and eta.

However, the algorithm failed to generate the correct result.

I wonder is there anything wrong the posterior function I have written? Or my way of thinking?

Comment: You did not provide reproducible example, but the thing that is obviously wrong is that you **ignore** all the y[1:(n-1)] values since you are storing the density for last y !

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, you are right. That's exactly the problem.... val=logf(x[i,],beta,y[i],sigma)+val will give the correct result. Many thanks.